# How can I remove duplicate results and merge objects that have a similar property on a mySQL query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, select

I'm using the mysql library with node.js to create this query:

```
SELECT vols.id_vol, vols.id_place, vols.id_vol_type, vols.id_user_creator, vols.name, vols.desc, vols.date_creation, vols.date_begin, vols.date_end, vols.duration, ' +
            ' vols.active, vols.start_time, vols.end_time, vols.insurance, vols.deleted, users.id_user, users.login, users.verified, users.photo_url, comments.message, comments.id_user, place.id_place, place.name AS placeName, place.lat, place.long' +
            ' FROM vols INNER JOIN users ON vols.id_user_creator = users.id_user INNER JOIN place ON vols.id_place = place.id_place LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.id_vol = vols.id_vol WHERE vols.deleted = 0
```

That returns this:

```
  "success": true,
  "vols": [
    {
      "vol": {
        "id_vol": 1,
        "id_place": 1,
        "id_vol_type": 2,
        "id_user_creator": 1,
      },
      "users": {
        "id_user": 1,
        "login": "",
        "verified": 0,
      },
      "comments": {
        "message": "Muito fixe",
        "id_user": 3
      },
{
      "vol": {
        "id_vol": 1,
        "id_place": 1,
        "id_vol_type": 2,
        "id_user_creator": 1,
      },
      "users": {
        "id_user": 1,
        "login": "",
        "verified": 0,
      },
      "comments": {
        "message": "ola",
        "id_user": 3
      }
```

It's currently repeating "vol" for each comment that exists with that specific vol ID. It is possible to stop showing duplicates and merge the comments on a single array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really possible, I mean you could do something with the group_concat function, but it would be messy.

What I usually do in similar cases is:

1. Query out all the relevant vols
2. Extract all the userIDs, placeIDs, commentIDs you want to look at.(While running through all the results to extract this data, it is a good idea to make an object for each result, and put them in index an index array(object) for each indexable parameter"user,place,comment")
3. Make 3 separate queries, one for each (users, places, comments), where you only select the relevant elements(use the `WHERE id IN (1,5,7,8,10)` filter)
4. run through the results of each of those queries, and insert them in the vol objects, using the index arrays(objects)

In javascript that would be something like(Sorry don't know node.js, so I don't have an excact solution

```
var results = db.queryResults('SELECT vols.id_vol, vols.id_place, vols.id_vol_type, vols.id_user_creator, vols.name, vols.desc, vols.date_creation, vols.date_begin, vols.date_end, vols.duration, vols.active, vols.start_time, vols.end_time, vols.insurance, vols.deleted FROM vols WHERE vols.deleted = 0');
var lookupByUserID = {};
var lookupByPlaceID = {};
var lookupByVolID = {};
var userIN = [];
var placeIN = [];
var volIN = [];
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
{
   var result = results[i];
   if (!lookupByUserID[result.id_user_creator])
       lookupByUserID[result.id_user_creator] = [];
   lookupByUserID[result.id_user_creator].push(result);

   if(!lookupByPlaceID[result.id_place])
      lookupByPlaceID[result.id_place] = [];
   lookupByPlaceID[result.id_place].push(result);

   lookupByVolID[result.id_vol] = result;
   userIN.push(result.id_user_creator);
   placeIN.push(result.id_place);
   volIN.push(result.id_vol);
   results.comments = [];
}

var userResults = db.queryResults('SELECT users.id_user, users.login, users.verified, users.photo_url FROM users WHERE id_user IN ('+userIN.join(',')+')');
var placeResults = db.queryResults('SELECT place.id_place, place.name AS placeName, place.lat, place.long FROM place WHERE id_place IN ('+placeIN.join(',')+')');
var commentResults = db.queryResults('SELECT comments.id_vol, comments.message, comments.id_user FROM comments WHERE id_vol IN ('+volIN.join(',')+')');
for (var i = 0; i < userResults.length; i++)
{
   var user = userResults[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < lookupByUserID[user.id_user].length; j++)
        lookupByUserID[user.id_user][j].created_by_user = user;
}
for (var i = 0; i < placeResults.length; i++)
{
   var place = placeResults[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < lookupByPlaceID[place.id_place].length; j++)
        lookupByPlaceID[place.id_place][j].place = place;
}
for (var i = 0; i < commentResults.length; i++)
{
    var comment = commentResults[i];
    lookupByVolID[comment.id_vol].comments.push(comment);
}
```

Now the object "results" should contain all the information